# analytics code generate for one domain and used for another

Tags: mod-rewrite, google-analytics

I had a website hosted on the server X (86.115.xx.xxx) with the domain www.AAAAAA.ro. I've made significant changes in the website and also re-branded it. I want to host the new version of the website on the same server but I want to change it's domain to www.BBBBBB.ro. I've deleted the source code of the old website from the server and added the code of the new website on the server. Currently both www.AAAAAA.ro and www.BBBBBB.ro domains point at the X server. www.AAAAAA.ro domain is permanently redirected (301 code) to www.BBBBBB.ro domain. The redirect is made using the following htaccess statements:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?BBBBBB\.ro$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://BBBBBB.ro/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My question:
If I use the analytics code generated for the www.AAAAAA.ro domain on the new website (the one that has the www.BBBBBB.ro) will it work ?. Please keep in mind that www.AAAAAA.ro domain is permanently redirected(301 code) to www.BBBBBB.ro domain.

Thanks,
Mihai Despa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If you are explicitly setting the domain in your GA code (`_setDomainName`), and it's set as your old domain, then the GA code is not going to trigger.  This is because GA will be unable to write its cookie.  So, you need to make sure this is either not set on your new domain, or else set it to the proper value.

All that aside, also note that the code will "work" in that it will continue to track.  However, GA uses first party cookies. So that means the cookies for your already established visitors (set on your old domain) will NOT carry over to the new domain. This means any visitors who already came to your site and had cookies will basically start out as a new visitor.

Unfortunately, preserving the current visitors is not an easy thing, unless you are willing to do some client-side redirection for a while, instead of server-side redirection.

Why?

So here's the thing.. you see, GA is pretty devious about ensuring the visitor info isn't tampered with when carrying it over.

Normally the way it is done is you use `_setAllowLinker` in your on-page code and then use `_link` in a given link's onclick.  This makes GA append its cookie info to the target URL to be carried over to the new domain.  (note: if you do want to go for client-side redirect, then you would basically just invoke the `_link` call on-page load instead of onclick. It will handle the redirect).

So here's where things get devious. In addition to the cookies and values, GA also passes a `__utmk` parameter, which in a nutshell is hash generated from an amalgamation of the other parameters and a small piece of the current domain's soul. There is some complicated js trickery within ga.js to make this happen and so far I have yet to find a reverse-engineered version of it w/ server-side code.

Now, assuming you sell your own soul to the devil to learn how to reproduce their magic trick, you are now faced with the next issue: passing that stuff in your redirect.

Grabbing the other cookies and passing them as parameters is "easy enough" within `.htaccess` or server config file or w/e.  But there isn't a script language available in that environment, so you'd have to use `RewriteMap` to reference an external script.  That's not *too* bad, though it does complicate things somewhat.  Oh also, `RewriteMap` cannot be declared in `.htaccess` so you can't stuff that there; have to put it in the server config file.  If you are already doing your rewrite rule in there then easy peasy, but if you're doing your rewrite rule in `.htaccess` then be aware of this.

So to sum up:

1. you have to reverse engineer exactly how `__utmk` is generated in `ga.js`, and port that to a server-side script
2. you have to use `RewriteMap` to call that script to generate that value
3. add the __utm`X` cookies and that __utmk parameter to the redirected URL
4. also, on your new domain, you need to add `_setAllowLinker` to your on-page GA code so that it will look for the URL params and use them

Alternative to this mess? As mentioned, if you are willing to for a while use GA's `_link` call on page load as the redirect method from siteA to siteB, this will allow the GA code to append the params (including the generated `__utmk` variable) to the target URL and successfully migrate the visitor to the new site.

NOTE: you will also want to append the `document.referrer` to your target URL in the `_link` push, and then add some code on your new domain to grab that too and pop `_setReferrerOverride` with that value, so that GA will record the original referrer instead of the dummy redirect page.

You can even do a `RewriteCondition` to check for the existence of `__utm` cookies and if they exist, redirect the visitor to a single page that has the GA redirect on it. If it don't exist, let the RewriteRule redirect to the new domain as usual.  This will cut down making new visitors having to jump through the hoop.

How long to let it client-side redirect? That depends on your longest conversion cycle. What are the conversion/goals for your site? For example, do you have a purchase funnel? How long on average does it take for a visitor to make a purchase? A day? A month? Pick your longest conversion cycle and wait about that long. There may be some edge cases that fall from the cracks from that, but that should be a lot more acceptable than losing ALL of them.  Or, leave it up indefinitely if you want.

If you don't want to do even that?  Well, pick a good time to deal with the visitor info slate being wiped clean, turn the rewrite rule on, and just deal with it.